# Load testing k6 browser + docker

Tags: docker, google-chrome, headless, k6, xk6-browser

Early sorry for bad english, but i try it. I'm writed load test in k6 browser. Now i need to start them in ci/cd (docker) in headless mode certainly. I get webgl error like this (image:node)

`Failed to obtain WebGL context\\n`

Сomputer specifications

```
Acer Swift
11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz   2.42 GHz
RAM 16,0 ГБ (enabled: 15,8 ГБ)
Iris Xe Graphics
```

before_script

```
- gpg -k
- gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/k6-archive-keyring.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C5AD17C747E3415A3642D57D77C6C491D6AC1D69
- echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/k6-archive-keyring.gpg] https://dl.k6.io/deb stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/k6.list
- apt-get update
- apt-get install -y k6 chromium gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libcairo2 libcups2 libfontconfig1 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libxss1 fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils
```

I try to set K6_BROWSER_ARGS=disable-gpu,enable-webgl but not get success result

I want to know - it's real? Load test on page with WebGL context in headless mode
Google not helped me. Who can help me link or another help